# Error android support design in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

I don't understand what is the error. The IDE gives me an error at 2 line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="dreamer.dareyou.HomeActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: remove space between double colon and android .... do it for next line too

Answer (score 0):

Like Mohsen said, you need to remove the space you have between `xmlns:` and `android`. Your third and fourth lines should look like this:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```